# Persistent Objects in Windows XP/Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, persistence, delphi-7

I am trying to make an AlarmSystem in Delphi 7, Windows XP. I have to register alarms in a Database (MS SQL Server 2000). But what if the server is down??? Well, I can imagine that I have to persist objects of TAlarm type. So, how can I do this? Maybe inheriting from TComponent??? Please, how can I do this??

Thanks a lot.

I am sorry about my English.

Here you have more info...
TAlarm is a class that descends from TObject, basically. There are 10 more classes that descend from TAlarm (some types of alarms). TAlarm has a field named FParams : TParams, and the child classes only have an Execute method. The field FParams can be of different types: TAlarmX1_Params, TAlarmX2_Params, etc, etc, etc.

Comment: You need to provide more information. What type is TAlarm based on? What exactly do you need to store?

Comment: The reason for asking more information is that how you should persist things depends on what exactly you're trying to save. If, for example, all you need to store is the date and time for an alarm and a description of what the alarm is for, you can save that in an INI file without storing all of the other parts of a class. However, if your needs are more complex than that, it may be better to store the entire class somehow. Without knowing more, it's hard to provide a good answer for you.

Comment: Sorry man. Now all you have new information in my question. I hope that helps. I appretiate your help.

Comment: Please see the follow-up question about storing **more than one** object: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673741/persisting-more-than-one-object-in-delphi-7-closed

Comment: @MLB, See the new example to persist more than one object.

Answer (score 4):

You can inheriting from TPersistent and then you can use the TJvAppXMLFileStorage ([JVCL](http://jvcl.delphi-jedi.org/)) component to serialize the TAlarm class.

***Save a Object***

```
uses
  JvAppXMLStorage;

Procedure SaveMyObject(MyAlarm : TAlarm)
var
  MyStore: TJvAppXMLFileStorage;
begin
  MyStore:= TJvAppXMLFileStorage.Create(nil);
  try
    MyStore.WritePersistent('', MyAlarm);
    MyStore.Xml.SaveToFile('C:\MyAlarm.xml');
  finally
    MyStore.Free;
  end;
end;
```

***Restore a Object***

```
uses
  JvAppXMLStorage;

Procedure LoadMyObject(MyAlarm : TAlarm)
var
  MyStore: TJvAppXMLFileStorage;
begin
  MyStore:= TJvAppXMLFileStorage.Create(nil);
  try
    MyStore.FileName:='C:\MyAlarm.xml';        
    MyStore.Xml.LoadFromFile('C:\MyAlarm.xml');
    MyStore.ReadPersistent('', MyAlarm);
  finally
    MyStore.Free;
  end;
end;
```

## UPDATE

If you need to persist more than one object to the XML file you must assign a path (unique id) to the WritePersistent and ReadPersistent methods.

See this example,

***Multiple Persist***

```
Procedure SaveMyObjects(MyObjects : Array of TComponent);
var
  MyStore: TJvAppXMLFileStorage;
  i      : integer;
begin
  MyStore:= TJvAppXMLFileStorage.Create(nil);
  try
    for i := Low(MyObjects) to High(MyObjects) do
     MyStore.WritePersistent(MyObjects[i].Name, MyObjects[i]); //In this case i use the name property of the component.
    MyStore.Xml.SaveToFile('C:\Tools\MyAlarm.xml');
   finally
    MyStore.Free;
  end;
end;
```

to save the components

```
SaveMyObjects([Button1,Button2,Edit1,Edit2]);
```

***Multiple LOAD***

```
Procedure LoadMyObjects(MyObjects:Array of TComponent);
var
  MyStore    : TJvAppXMLFileStorage;
  i          : integer;

begin
  MyStore:= TJvAppXMLFileStorage.Create(nil);
  try
    MyStore.FileName:='C:\Tools\MyAlarm.xml';
    MyStore.Xml.LoadFromFile('C:\Tools\MyAlarm.xml');
    for i := Low(MyObjects) to High(MyObjects) do
      MyStore.ReadPersistent(MyObjects[i].Name, MyObjects[i]);
  finally
    MyStore.Free;
  end;
end;
```

To restore the properties

```
LoadMyObjects([Button1,Button2,Edit1,Edit2]);
```

Another option to load

```
Procedure LoadMyObjectById(Id:String;MyObject:TComponent); //using the id of the object
var
  MyStore    : TJvAppXMLFileStorage;
  i          : integer;

begin
  MyStore:= TJvAppXMLFileStorage.Create(nil);
  try
    MyStore.FileName:='C:\Tools\MyAlarm.xml';
    MyStore.Xml.LoadFromFile('C:\Tools\MyAlarm.xml');
   MyStore.ReadPersistent(id, MyObject);
  finally
    MyStore.Free;
  end;
end;
```

you must run it this way

```
LoadMyObjectById(Button1.Name,Button1); //Again using the Name property.
```

I hope this example will be useful ;)

Comment: I see no code that assigns a new value to the `MyAlarm` arguments, so why are they passed by reference?

Comment: Ok, that's right... but what if I have to persist more than one object?? How to read more than one object from the XML???

Comment: You can use a tObjectList to hold onto your multiple objects and iterate thru the list for writing.

Comment: Skamradt, TObjectList doesn't descend from TPersistent, so it can't be used in the given function. Furthermore, Yulien seems to have tried saving more than one object using Rruz's function, but each object overwrites the previous. See the follow-up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673741/persisting-more-than-one-object-in-delphi-7-closed

Answer (score 0):

You could persist the information in an XML or INI file locally.  That doesn't require changing what TAlarm descends from.  You would need to manually persist and restore all the properties that you wish to persist locally though.  Shouldn't be that complicated.

Comment: I'm sorry my friend, but I have never persisted objects. Please, tell me where I can find any tutorial or manual about persistence. How can I persist the information locally in an XML or INI file?? give an example please. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

If the server where you're supposed to be saving your data to is down, the best course of action is usually to cause the operation to fail and return an error.  This way you don't need two separate sets of serialization code, both of which have to be  kept in sync with each other,  and a way  to take your local data and upload it to the server once it's back up.

Plus, if your app depends on a remote server, it's likely that the user won't be able to do much with it offline anyway,  so this isn't as bad of an idea as it may dound at first from a user-interface perspective.

Answer (score 0):

I used a local database, an Access mdb file accessed thru ADO, with the same schema than the server. When connection recovers, I did a synchronization. But, nowadays, I have dropped this technique; wnen connection is lost or server is down, the application fails.