# Persisting more than one object in Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, persistence, delphi-7, tpersistent

This is not a duplicate but a **follow-up** to "[Persistent Objects in Windows XP/Delphi 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663166/persistent-objects-in-windows-xp-delphi-7)."

I need to persist **more than one** object in Delphi 7, and the objects are a class family. [RRUZ's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663166/persistent-objects-in-windows-xp-delphi-7/1663329#1663329) suggests I inherit from `TPersistent` and use `TJvAppXMLFileStorage`, but when I use its `WritePersistent` method, it overwrite one object with the next object in the XML file.

I have to save objects (TAlarms, and descendants) later in a database, so I have to recover them from the file.

How can I persist more than one object in the same file and then load these objects from the file?

Comment: Yulien, please stop posting the same thing over and over again in new messages, and stick to your original post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663166/persistent-objects-in-windows-xp-delphi-7

Comment: @Ken Good catch.  I completely missed that.  Voted to close

Comment: @Mark: I only caught it  because it's the third in two days on the same subject from the same poster.

Comment: @MLB, See the new example to persist more than one object. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663166/persistent-objects-in-windows-xp-delphi-7